# Who is Lou Bayou (NBA Jam Commentary on iPhone)?

Tags: ios, nba-jam-2010

The commentator has at least two variations of saying (or singing) 'Lou Bayou' or something similar. 
Question is, who is he?
Or does he say something different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe he is singing ["Blue Bayou"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Bayou). It's a pun on "blew by you", he says it when you go past a defender.

Comment: Seems feasible!